# How to Set value for Hidden field in Razr MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my application I need to pass some values from one page(page A to Page B) to another page.
For this I am using Session variables(I cannot use Tempdata as it doesn't work on loadbalancing).
In Page A I am setting the Session Variable.
In Page B I need to retrieve the above Session variable.
For this I am using a Hidden field in Page B.
I dont know how to set the Session Variable to Hidden Field in  Page B.

#### Page A

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetFileName(string updatedfileName, string orgfileName)
{
    Session["OrgFileName"] = orgfileName;
    Session["UpdatedFileName"] = updatedfileName;
    var result = myService.getFile(updatedfileName, orgfileName);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

#### Page B

```
<div style="display:none" >         
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="hdnfilename" />
</div>
```

Comment: The whole point of session variables is that you don't need a hidden field.  Did you correctly set up external session storage?

Comment: How can I call the session field in javascript(jquery)?

Comment: Session is a server-side variable, you can't get it from the client side (Javascript)

Comment: The whole point of using session variables is that they are available between pages for a give user. Why did you think you needed a hidden field for this? Also, you should probably be using the Html helpers for your inputs.

Comment: Behind the scenes the session is an ID stored in a cookie at the client's browser. When the server receives a cookie with the same ID he gave to user X, he know that he is talking to user X, so he gets the items stored in the server side for the user using the ID from the session's cookie (think of it as server-side dictionary with key-value of ID-SessionData

Comment: It sounds like you shouldn't be using session at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the controller of "Page B", set a `ViewBag.MyValue`to your session variable and apply it to the hidden's value.

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.MyValue = Session["MYVALUE"];
```

**View**

```
<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.MyValue" id="hdnfilename" />
```

If you need to get a session variable from JavaScript, you will need to develop an action that will return the session variable and consume it with JavaScript/jQuery, like this:

```
// Controller code
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetSessionVarValue(string key)
{
    return Json(new { key = key, value = Session[key] }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

// JavaScript code
var mySessionValue;
$.getJSON("/GetSessionVarValue", "MYKEY", function(data) {
    mySessionValue = data.value;
});
```

You may take care with `Session` variables in load balance, too. The best way to secure store session variables is changing the state of session mode configuration to `StateServer`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. But its not working. What is "key" here? and why do I need key? here is my controller code.....public JsonResult GetSessionVarValue(string orgfilename)
        {
            return Json(new { key = orgfilename, value = Session["OrgFileName"] }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Comment: This action was planned to get any session variable. The `key`argument is the name of the key inside the `Session` collection. You may replace `Session["OrgFileName"]` by `Session[key]` and pass the string "OrgFileName" to the action as argument. Using HTTP GET, your URL would be `/GetSessionVarValue?key=OrgFileName`